# Querying in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to write a Query in Exact Target to pull some report. I understand that what we call Tables in SQL is termed as 'Data Views' here. So where can we see those Data View definitions, I mean column names, primary key details and relationship to other tables? I am beginner for Marketing Cloud and couldn't find straight cut answers in SF Communities and please correct me if I have referred something wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Data Extensions**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/getting_started_with_data_extensions/) in SFMC are equivalent to database tables.  Those can include any columns that suit your requirements.

The **Data Views** (**System Data Views**), are read-only tables of Subscriber and Subscriber activity data.

The schemas for those are found on the [**Query Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) page.

Query Activities can only do SQL Select statements and add/update/append another Data Extension.

If you're looking for some syntax help, SFMC Query Activities follow [**Microsoft Transact-SQL**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.130).aspx) (T-SQL) conventions (with a few exceptions).